# Rails QRCode rendered as HTML table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, qr-code

Searching for Rails QRCoding, I met [Rails QRCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577669/rqrcode-error-for-ruby-on-rails)
 I really liked the rendering of QRCode as an HTML table, but, although  I use following styles to define black and white cells,

```
.black {border-left: solid 1px #000; border-right: solid 1px #000;} 
.white {border-left: solid 1px #fff; border-right: solid 1px #fff;}
```

The resulting QRCode is not readable at all :( ....any suggestions about my missunderstanding of QRCodes like this shown by [user783437](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783437/user783437)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the example listed in the [docs](http://whomwah.github.io/rqrcode/).  Can you try this example and see if that works?  If not then you most likely have some extra CSS elsewhere in your application that is getting mixed in.

## Controller

```
require 'rqrcode'

def qrcode
 @qr = RQRCode::QRCode.new('hello world')
end
```

## View

```
<style type="text/css">
 table {
  border-width: 0;
  border-style: none;
  border-color: #0000ff;
  border-collapse: collapse;
 }
 td {
   border-width: 0;
   border-style: none;
   border-color: #0000ff;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   width: 10px;
   height: 10px;
 }
 td.black { background-color: #000; }
 td.white { background-color: #fff; }
</style>

<table>
 <% @qr.modules.each_index do |x| -%>
   <tr>
   <% @qr.modules.each_index do |y| -%>
    <% if @qr.dark?(x,y) -%>
    <td class="black"/>
    <% else -%>
    <td class="white"/>
    <% end -%>
   <% end -%>
   </tr>
 <% end -%>
</table>
```

Comment: Yeah ! it does ....however now I will keep googling to show it a little smaller :D